# Symbol identification: eye on hand (image included)

Tags: 20th-century-boys

I saw this at a con recently and was wondering what the eye/hand/eye symbol appeared in. It looks familiar but I can't remember where from.

[image]

Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That's from [20th Century boys](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/20th_Century_Boys), a manga series by Naoki Urasawa (who also created "Monster"). And the man in the picture is referred to as "Friend".

[image]

Though the symbol originated from:

> comic books that the children read when they were kids that indicated a page turn.